# bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' in make -j($nproc)

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, terminal, sh

I'm trying to build the LLVM Gold plugin. but it's giving error.

```
cmake ../llvm -DLLVM_BINUTILS_INCDIR="path/to/binutils/include"
make -j($nproc)
```

It's giving the following error.
`bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`

and how to remove it?

Comment: It should be `make -j$(nproc)` because  `nproc` is a command, not a variable - voting to close as a typo